# JPA cascade not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I have two JPA entities: `Person` and `Address`.

The `Address` class is a common classe used by different classes.

On the `Person` class I have a `@OneToOne` relationship as this:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;
```

I am using JPA with `RESOURCE_LOCAL` option, on a standalone application.

I instantiate a `Person`, an `Address`, fill all the attributes and ask the JPA to save all by `em.merge(person)`.

Since the records already exists on the database, I expect JPA to update all the information. But it only updates the address information if I also change something on the person instance too. If I just change some information of the address instance and ask JPA to save the `Person`, nothing is updated. I checked the generated SQL by Hibernate and right at the `merge()` operation, it only executes a `SELECT` at the `person` table (joining the `address` table).

In both `Person` and `Address` classes I have `equals()` and `hashCode()` with Eclipse's default implementation.

Any ideas on how to cascade the update to the `Address`?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code, I mean the one that creates and merges those objects?

Comment: Hi @bhesh-gurung! The code basically instantiate the Person and the Address, sets the address on the Person instance and call em.merge(person). But the two of them already exists on the database, so, I expect an update.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Person` class:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;
```

While saving, you can do the following:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

session.beginTransaction();
session.saveOrUpdate(person);

// Hibernate will automatically update because the object is in persistence context
address.setStreetName(" Updated Street Name"); 

// Hibernate will automatically update because the object is in persistence context
person.setPersonName("Updated Name"); 

session.getTransaction().commit();

// person object is now detached
session.close();
```

Now, if you try to update either `Person` or `Address`, they will not be updated because the object is now detached:

```
user.setUserName("If you try to update, it will not since session is closed");
address.setStreetName("If you try to update, it will not since session is closed");
```